# Accessing an application page with facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to access a facebook page's conversations using the graph api.
Accessing the page itself (with `/{page_id}`) is fine, but I get on `oauth exception` for the conversations.

My request in the graph explorer is this one : 
`/{page_id}/conversations` where `{page_id}` is, well, the page id :)

and the error is

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10
  }
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations), the required authorization is `read_page_mailboxes`, which I granted. Here are the rights of my token as shown in the oauth debugger :

```
public_profile, basic_info, read_page_mailboxes, manage_pages, user_friends
```

Are there other permissions I'm supposed to require ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, just asking for the permission itself is not the right way to access to this page informations.

You have to recover the page access token located at `/{page_id}?fields=access_token` and use this token in order to access the conversations.

Comment: +1 exactly, you need to use the `page access token` for that!

Comment: but where does one use the access_token once retrieved?